# kendo.all.min scoping issues while using requirejs

Tags: kendo-ui

We have run into some issues with the kendo.all.min file while using RequireJS.

**Errors**

> *Kendo Grid:*
>
> Uncaught Reference Error: className is undefined
>
> *Kendo Tooltip:*
>
> Uncaught Reference Error: autoHide is undefined

Further, if we remove the kendo.all.min and use the modular-based loading of kendo widgets (e.g. kendo.grid.min, kendo.tooltip.min) within requirejs, there are no errors. This makes me think that they have misconfigured their kendo.all.min file.

While we understand good practice would be to use the modular based loading of Kendo with requirejs, we would like to continue using just the kendo.all.min file.

Can anyone confirm that this is an issue in the kendo.all.min file?

We are using Kendo Version 2014.1.318.

Answer (score 0):

At the time being kendo.all.min.js doesn't support loading with RequireJS. More info is available in the [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/using-kendo-with-requirejs).